# How to determine the most efficient voltage transformation?

Tags: voltage, ac, dc

I have a 12VDC battery bank and an appliance I want to run that requires 26VDC input. The power requirement for operation is approximately 100 watts. I have a 12VDC power adapter (not sure if it is switching or linear) that outputs 26VDC. I also have a 120VAC adapter that can supply the machine the 26VDC.

Is it more energy efficient to "step-up" the DC-DC or "step-down" in the AC-DC? Assuming the efficiency of the power supplies are similar (can that be assumed?)

Sorry, a software engineer not an EE but I am curious as to this question in general. Is there a formula? I couldn't really find anything on the efficiencies of stepping up vs down especially from lower vs higher voltages to a target voltage and where some kind of break even point may be obtained.

Comment: If it takes 12 V input and gives 26 V output, it's a switching power supply. Linear can't increase voltage, only decrease it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the efficiency of the converter itself. The formula would be efficiency=(power out)/(power in). Simple enough.

Two supplies with similar efficiency ratings will indeed have the same losses, regardless of their design, when considered in isolation.

The picture is a bit different when you consider what’s supplying your power. Your system losses include the supply wiring, too. And here there’s a distinct difference: using higher supply voltage and stepping down leads to less I2R loss at the input side than using a lower voltage and stepping up. This fact explains why one would choose a higher voltage for power delivery, then regulate down at point-of-use.

Comment: Thanks. While "it depends" is not the most gratifying answer, I can see how it is the most obvious. I was hoping for an elaborate equation but it seems ultimately it comes down to testing the efficiency of the transformers.

Comment: Any place in your circuit where you have current being forced through a resistance is a point of power loss. Inductors, transformers and capacitors aren’t perfect: they have resistance. So do active switching elements like transistors and MOSFETs. It is possible to model all these mathematically and predict the losses with tools like Spice. The takeaway though is that if you can reduce either I or R, you reduce losses. Since the I contribution is I *squared* there’s great benefit in reducing it.

Answer (score 3):

Which ever one makes the most heat when you use it is the least efficient.

If one is smaller than the other it may get hotter just because the heat it makes is more concentrated,  so you may have to measure the actual heat it makes not the temperature

Comment: Makes complete sense. As a matter of curiosity, can this be measured in a systematic way with e.g. a multimeter? I mean I have an (cheapish) infrared thermometer. Would taking measurements at the power converter really reveal their relative efficiencies accurately enough to be meaningful?

Comment: A systematic way would be use a calorimeter. which for this test  might be an insulated box (cooler box) with a bag of water in it,

Answer (score 2):

1. If your 12V battery bank ultimately charges from 120V AC then you will have some efficiency losses related to charging it.  After that you will have a second set of losses going from 12V to 26V.
2. On the other hand, going directly from 120V to 26V just involves one voltage conversion, so one efficiency loss.

It's pretty likely that option 2 is more efficient just because you are only converting voltages once vs twice (but we can't really say for sure without more info).

Answer (score 2):

Do you also charge the battery from AC? If so, factoring in the losses from charging the battery and then up converting it, then AC adapter will certainly be more efficient then the two step conversion with the battery.

Conversely if the battery is charged by something like solar it's probably better to use the battery regardless of efficiency since otherwise that sunlight will be wasted.

Comment: Yes thanks, makes sense. The batteries are generally charged via solar MPPT charger but this question is more for the "nighttime" calculation where I am not necessarily receiving any input current. The AC would potentially be supplied from a portable LiFePO4 battery (again charged by solar during the day) but at night would be technically stepped up from 14.4VDC to 110VAC and then back down to the 26VDC. Alternatively 110VAC could be from a generator that outputs 110. To make the question simpler I was trying to ignore the ultimate source of the power as a black box.

Answer (score 1):

Step-ups tend to be 90 to 99% and current losses are reduced.   Step-down tends to be 82 to 99%,  in this reverse voltage range but it depends on which losses you count and which design you choose as there is a wide variance.  Both supplies had to step down from AC initially.

Comment: Black boxing "where the power originates" for a moment, why do step-ups tend to be slightly more efficient? I am asking for purely edification purposes.

Comment: Transfer of power at higher voltages for the same power at lower currents reduces conduction losses